# Help me, was given a Mathematical problem to figure out, but the answers told me it was just demorgans law in c code.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Was given this to figure out.  He said its mathematical, no its not homework.  More of one guy trying to prove he is smarter than me.

The code:

```
(!(a&&b)) == |!a||!b|  T
!(a||b) == !a&&!b
```

I think it might be some symbolic logic, but couldn't figure out from reading about symbolic mathematics from google searches.  That is only my guess.

Comment: This resembles C code, so I believe '!' means NOT, '&&' means AND , '||' means OR.

Comment: Typically && refers to logical AND, || refers to logical or and ! refers to logical not.  Not (a AND b) = not A or not B.  ie) if a AND b is false, then either a is false or b is false.$$ $$

The second says not (A or B) = not A and not B.  ie) if neither A or B is true, then both A is false, and B is false.  As avatar has said, these are de morgan's laws.

Comment: @muzzlator I read a mathematical logic book and it never used that notation, could you point me in the direction of some resources that use that notation.

Comment: A great number of programming languages uses this notation.  Find a book on say C programming and you'll see it used.

Comment: PLEASE change the title of this question!

Comment: @SteveD that is why there is an edit option.  If you can do better then do better.

Comment: Why is the burden on me to edit *your* question? And why are you giving me attitude? The title is not specific in the least, and doesn't convey any sense of what the question is about. It should be changed (**by you**).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is (almost) DeMorgan's laws written in C-language syntax (though other languages use the same syntax, too). Writing it a bit more tidily, it would be:

```
!(a && b) = (!a) || (!b)

!(a || b) = (!a) && (!b)
```

That's not exactly what you wrote, but I expect it's what you meant to write.

I don't know anything about symbolic logic notation, but in set-theoretic notation, the equivalent laws would be:

$$ (A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c $$

$$ (A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c $$

Or, in English (almost):

```
not(A and B) = (not A) or  (not B)
not(A or  B) = (not A) and (not B)
```

Comment: In symbolic logic notation, your answers would be $\neg (A \wedge B) \Leftrightarrow \neg A \vee \neg B$ and $\neg (A \vee B) \Leftrightarrow \neg A \wedge \neg B$.

Comment: To get those symbols in $\LaTeX$, the following codes can be used: \neg = $\neg$ (not), \wedge = $\wedge$ (and), and \vee = $\vee$ (or).

Comment: Thanks, Joe. That symbolism did come to mind after a bit of thought, but I figured two versions of the equations were enough, already.

Answer (score 6):

This is De Morgan's law. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: could you translate it to De Morgan's law. I know the law, but never saw it written like that.

Comment: Pedro and I have translated it in the comments section under the question.